# Detect planes in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

How do I get notified when the app has detected at least one plane in ARKit?

I'm currently doing something like this but it's not firing/it's not related:

```
extension MyViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
    internal func setupAR() {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        sceneView.session.delegate = self
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    public func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        if !anchors.isEmpty {
            print("ANCHORS NOT EMPTY")
            planesDetectedState()
        } else {
            print("Anchors is empty")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as correct answer if it solved your issue. That way, other folks checking out this question can be sure that the solution worked. If the answers didn’t work, it would be great if you could let us know. Tx.

Comment: @Manganese I still have to test them out. In the meantime thanks for your help

Comment: Sure, hope it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please **add** Anchors first to **update** those. You need to use the following function:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        guard let frame = session.currentFrame else { return }
        print("Just added an anchor and felt so good")
}
```

Plus, you wouldn't be able to see any plane, unless you add a node to you anchor, which you can do by:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        // Add a planeNode and make it a child to the node automatically added.
}
```

I would furthermore suggest, download the starter code which would be easy to follow for exactly the thing you are thinking about.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/building_your_first_ar_experience

Answer (score 4):

If you want to detect `ARAnchors` there are several ways to do so.

**1st:** You can use the `ARSessionDelegate` Callback:

```
public func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) { }
```

Which:

> Tells the delegate that one or more anchors have been added to the
>   session.

An example of using this callback would thus be like so:

```
extension UIViewController: ARSessionDelegate{

    public func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        //1. If We Have At Least One ARAnchor Detected The Log The Information
        if !anchors.isEmpty {

            anchors.forEach { (anchor) in

                print("""
                      The Type Of Anchor = \(anchor.classForCoder)
                      The Anchor Identifier = \(anchor.identifier)
                      The Anchor Translation = X: \(anchor.transform.columns.3.x), Y: \(anchor.transform.columns.3.y), Z: \(anchor.transform.columns.3.z)
                      """)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**2nd:** You could use the `ARSCNViewDelegate` callback:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

Which:

> Tells the delegate that a SceneKit node corresponding to a new AR
>   anchor has been added to the scene.

An example of using this callback would thus be like so:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. Check An ARPlane Anchor Has Been Detected
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

        //2. Get The Width & Height Of The Plane
        let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
        let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)

        //3. Create An SCNPlane So We Can Visualize The Plane Detected
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

        //4. Set It's Colour
        plane.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan

        //5. Create An SCNNode To Hold Our Plane
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

        //6. Position & Rotate It
        let x = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.x)
        let y = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.y)
        let z = CGFloat(planeAnchor.center.z)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x,y,z)
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

        //7. Add It To The Node For Anchor
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

    }

}
```