# ARKit: notification upon feature point detection?

Tags: ios, detection, arkit

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354915/detect-planes-in-arkit) and others explain how to get notified when ARKit detects anchors or planes, but how do you get notifications when ARKit detects feature points?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the APIs it's somewhat similar to the answers that you have linked to.

Using `ARSessionDelegate session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` you can access the `rawFeaturePoints` of the ARFrame that just got passed in.

So it would look something like:

```
// Not actually tested
class MyARSessionDelegate: ARSessionDelegate {
    var previouslyDetectedPointCount = 0
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        // Check if new points are detected
        if previouslyDetectedPointCount != frame.rawFeaturePoints?.points.count {
            // point count has changed
             previouslyDetectedPointCount = frame.rawFeaturePoints!.points.count
        }
    }
}
```

Though as to why you would want to be looking for the specific points is curious. The documentation clearly states:

> ARKit does not guarantee that the number and arrangement of raw
>   feature points will remain stable between software releases, or even
>   between subsequent frames in the same session.

Comment: Not looking for specific points, just want to know when feature points have been detected for the first time. This was the solution we adopted after posting the question, but thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like the ideal solution, but it works. Implement the `func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` function from the `ARSessionDelegate` protocol, and check for feature points in each frame.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    // Show tap icon once we find feature points
    if !detectedFeaturePoints, let points = frame.rawFeaturePoints?.points, let firstPoint = points.first {
        detectedFeaturePoints = true
    }
}
```